# Rails: Defining methods for my controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model, controller

Newbie question! I'm trying to get my head around how I can set up specific Active Record searches which I then call from my controllers. Why is this throwing an undefined method error?

**method defined in the Model:**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :category, :date_end, :date_start, :description, :time_start, :title, :venue, :image


    def next_seven_days
        t = Time.now
        Event.where("date_end BETWEEN ? AND ?", t, t+7.days).order("date_end ASC")
    end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def index
    @events = Event.next_seven_days     
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you haven't defined the method you're calling as a class method

try

```
 def self.next_seven_days
```

in the activerecord class instead of what you have